# How do I turn secure boot off in UEFI BIOS on an ASUS TUF Gaming board?

Tags: bios, uefi, secure-boot, asus

I've tried following various tutorials.  The closest one to displaying similar screens as I have was this: https://www.technorms.com/45538/disable-enable-secure-boot-asus-motherboard-uefi-bios-utility

It's advice was to:

1. Open BIOS
2. Go to `Advanced -> Boot -> Secure\Boot -> Key Management`
3. Delete the `PK Management Key` and only that key

It then showed `Secure Boot State` switching to "Disabled."  Unfortunately, mine switches to "Setup."  Perhaps these two are the same thing and I actually do have Secure Boot disabled, but an issue unrelated to this question and its answer persists (which is why I have doubts).

**Is "setup" the same as "disabled"?  And if not, how do I get to "disabled"?**

Comment: there is a youtube video about enabling it for asus tuf.. and one on disabling it for asus, looks same as the screen for asus tuf .. here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnOHi0w77bU  talks about  clearing keys and then it disables it and says you can put them back as they are default... But anyhow, shows how to disable secure boot  in that video. Not sure if it's exactly applicable to your one but try it

Comment: Hmmm.  Same exact thing.  Maybe they just changed the name from "disabled" to "setup"

Comment: Maybe,  You could test if that's so. Try looking to see what an OS says about whether secure boot is enabled or not e.g.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/you-need-to-enable-secure-boot-windows  or https://techoverflow.net/2019/05/23/how-to-check-if-secure-boot-is-enabled-on-ubuntu/ (if using ubuntu to check you can run ubuntu off a usb stick).

Comment: Thank you.  You were correct, and if you'd like to replace my answer I will accept yours.

Comment: I followed what was mentioned in the question and description. It seems like BIOS took the changes and Secure Boot State does say "SETUP." However, my system keeps loading into UFEI MODE all the time never legacy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that "setup" does in fact equate to "disabled".

The steps above are functional, and one can verify this with:

- In a unix system, either of

  - `mokutil --sb-state`
  - or `dmesg | grep -E 'secure|nvidia'`
- In windows:

  - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/you-need-to-enable-secure-boot-windows